# SharePoint 2010: Set Default Content Type Across Site Collection Libraries, or Alternatively Bulk Edit Content Types in a Library

Tags: 2010, content-type

We have project staff who upload hundreds of documents during the day that are all the same content type with little variation. This is done across dozens of libraries. This means I can't just set a default document type to one particular library the entire group uses.

Is there any way to set a default content type across the entire site collection? Or, alternatively is there way to bulk edit content types in a library?

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries exists, you need to :

1. use powershell scripting to identify the columns used by each document
2. With this, create the content type you need
3. use powershell scripting to add your new content type on each library
4. use powershell scripting to change the content type of each document
5. use powershell scripting to add specific columns to the new content type if needed
6. use powershell scripting to remove the old content type

Caution : with this aproach somes columns on librairies can be present but not used or needed..

In case of the librariy do not exist, you need, like me, to set a defaut custom content type when a library is create.
Here is a document given an approach to do it : 
[Guidance for editing pre-defined content types and site columns](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=260922)